# How to share a certain instance with multiple modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Suppose that I have my main.js module, a shared.js and a foo.js modules.

main.js file is the following:

```
function Main(){
    this.shared = new Shared();
}

Main.prototype.getFoo(){
    return new Foo();
}
```

Now, in order to work Foo needs the 'shared' instance created in Main, Is there an approach I could take other than passing 'shared' to Foo so that Foo can always access that 'shared' instance?

Edit: Main is instantiated once.

Comment: Other than passing it (or the `Main` instance) to `Foo` in some way then I'd say, no, not possible (unless having a single instance of `Shared` throughout your entire app is okay, but looking at the code I think it's not).

Answer (score 0):

You may use global variables to do this but this is not the propper way. Far better you can use require() to do this. In the main.js add the following:

```
module.exports = Main;
```

Now in any other module you need this only require it.

```
var Main = require('./main.js');
```

That's it. This works also between different packages.

Comment: How does that share `.shared` with `Foo`?

Comment: That was only a very short example. You may do it with whatever file you want. And the question author did it right in his answer here, now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by directly passing the shared instance to the exports.

shared.js:

```
module.exports = new Shared();

function Shared(){
    ...
}
```

main.js:

```
function Main(){
    this.shared = require('./shared.js');
}

Main.prototype.getFoo = function(){
    return new Foo();
}
```

foo.js:

```
function Foo(){
    this.shared = requrie('./shared.js');
}
```

This way Foo will use the same 'shared' instance used in Main without having to pass it. I'm not sure if this is a 'correct' way to achieve my needs but is doing its job.

Comment: In your original question, you instantiated `Shared` for each instance of `Main`. In this answer, you instantiate `Shared` just once. If that's your intention, great, but it's not the same as your question.

Comment: I didn't mention that Main is instantiated just once, thanks pointing it out